# 'Direct self-reference leading to cycle' Jackson and inheritance

Tags: java, jpa, inheritance, jackson, jaxb

I have a class something like this:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
@Audited
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "tipo_hito")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(propOrder = { "idHito" })
@XmlRootElement(name = "Hito")
public abstract class Hito implements Ordenable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "idhito", nullable = false)
    private Long idHito;

    public Long getIdHito() { return idHito; }

    public void setIdHito(Long idHito) { this.idHito = idHito; }
}
```

And a class that extends the class above

```
@MappedSuperclass
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(propOrder = {..., "successors", "predecessors", ...})
@XmlRootElement(name = "HitoOrdenable")
public abstract class HitoOrdenable extends Hito {

    @XmlElement(name = "predecessors")
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name = "succession", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "idpredecessor") }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "idsuccessor") })
    private Set<Hito> predecessors;

    @XmlElement(name = "successors")
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name = "succession", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "idsuccessor") }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "idpredecessor") })
    private Set<Hito> successors;

    // More code...
}
```

Now, the error it's when I try to get a `HitoOrdenable`. Because for example I can have:

```
Hito1
  Hito2-SuccessorOf1
  Hito3-SuccessorOf1
    Hito4-SuccessorOf3
Hito5
  Hito6-SuccessorOf5
```

So, when I get `Hito1` this has Successors `Hito2` and `Hito3`. But when I get `Hito2` it has predecessor `Hito1`. So start a "infinite cycle".

The exact error is:

> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Direct
>   self-reference leading to cycle (through reference chain:
>   ar.gob.buenosaires.esb.domain.message.ProyectoRespMsg["proyectos"]->java.util.ArrayList[5]->ar.gob.buenosaires.domain.Proyecto["obras"]->org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag[0]->ar.gob.buenosaires.domain.Obra["hitos"]->org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag[0]->ar.gob.buenosaires.domain.HitoObra["hitoOrdenable"])

I tried to set @JsonIgnore in `predecessors` but it doesn't works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a few days of trys. The only solution that we found was to add in  `@JsonIgnoreProperties({"predecessors"})` and  `@JsonIdentityInfo(generator=ObjectIdGenerators.IntSequenceGenerator.class, property="idHitoAux")`

**HitoOrdenable.java**

```
  @MappedSuperclass
  @XmlType(propOrder = {..., "successors", "predecessors", ...})
  @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
  @JsonIgnoreProperties({ "predecessors" })
  @JsonIdentityInfo(generator=ObjectIdGenerators.IntSequenceGenerator.class, property="idHitoAux")
```

**Hito.java**

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
@Audited
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(propOrder = { "idHito", "tipoHito"})
@JsonIgnoreProperties({"idHitoAux", "hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler"})
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.EXISTING_PROPERTY, visible = true, property = "tipoHito")
@JsonSubTypes({
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(name = "hito_obra", value = HitoObra.class),
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(name = "hito_proyecto", value = HitoProyecto.class)
})<
```

With JsonIgnoreProperties we prevent infinite cycle between sucessors and predecessors and with `@JsonIdentityInfo` it was because if we use `"idHito"` instead of `"idHitoAux"` (who its equals to idHito) Hibernate transformed idHito to null. So with `"idHitoAux"` Hibernate can identify every object in the List.

PD: After that solution we had a problem with deserialization of `abstract class Hito`, so our solution it wass to add `@JsonSubTypes`.

Greetings!